# C# deserialize xml error ReadElementContentAs() methods cannot be called on an element that has child elements

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I've looked at several similar SO questions but still can't solve my issue.

Using the following code I try to deserialize:

```
  private static QCOrderInfo GetOrderFromXml(XDocument xmlDoc){
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(QCOrderInfo));
    var post = 
    (QCOrderInfo)serializer.Deserialize(xmlDoc.Root.CreateReader());

    return post ?? new QCOrderInfo();
   }
```

The error resulting:

```
  System.Xml.XmlException: ReadElementContentAs() methods cannot be called on an element that has child elements.
  at System.Xml.XmlReader.SetupReadElementContentAsXxx(String methodName)
```

Too much code to post but view working dotnetfiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/pRCWQh

Comment: That's a huge XML. Try to dissect it to localize the place which produces the error.

Comment: The code works reading from a file using XmlReader.  There is one issue with the  node <ApprovedAppraisers>
      <Appraiser>Jane Doo</Appraiser>
    </ApprovedAppraisers>  The property in the class is defined as a string[] which will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your appoved appraisers are not getting deserialized properly.

So add a class

```
[Serializable]
    public class ApprovedAppraisers
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Appraiser")]
        public string Appraiser { get; set; }
    }
```

And  change

```
public string[] ApprovedAppraisers { get; set; }
```

to

```
public ApprovedAppraisers[] ApprovedAppraisers { get; set; }
```